# C++: operator overloading for matrix

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

Hey guys i have to write a class with overloading operators +,-,*,<<,>> , in my college we have a site with compiler, when i click submit i get 3/4 correct but 1 incorrect, so i need your help to tell me if my operator * is overloaded right.

Here is my code for operator *

```
Matrica &operator * (Matrica &m)
    {
        float tot=0;
        for (int i=0;i<m.redici;i++)
        {
            for (int j=0;j<m.koloni;j++)
            {
                for (int k=0;k<m.koloni;k++)
                {
                    tot+=matrix[i][k]*m.matrix[k][j];
                }
                matrix[i][j]=tot;
                tot=0;
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
```

i get wrong results for this test case:
[Wrong TestCase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sn9N.png)

Thanks, Filip

Comment: You generally don't want to modify your instance in any of the non-assignment operators (`*/+-`), you should return a new object. Also, if you could translate your variables to english, that would be great.

Comment: I have no idea how to interpret that linked test case. Please show input/output as text in the question (unless it can't be represented as text) and explain how to interpret it.

Comment: Note that you are modifying your matrix *while* calculating the product.

Comment: I don't know the platform you are running this question on, but a simple fix would be `Matrica temp(*this);` then do your calculations on `temp`, and then `return temp;`.  Right now, you are mutating the existing matrix object, which is not the way `operator *` should behave.  Instead, you should be making a copy of the matrix, work on the copy, return the copy.

Comment: Ah sorry, first block is INPUT of program, second block is right output that should be, third block is OUTPUT of my program and the fourth is difference from MY output and the output should be.

Comment: Matrica means MATRIX, koloni means COLUMNS, redici means ROWS

Comment: @Bob__ if i want to create a new object of class Matrica(Matrix) i need to overload [][] operator to use New[i][j] but in this example only i need to overload `+,-,*,>>,<<` operators. Thanks

Comment: @FilipGorgievski you don't need to overload indexing operator. You can access private members of the other object just fine as long as it's a member- or friend function.

Comment: @FilipGorgievski Why not try what I suggested?  If the arrays are simple 2D arrays, then the approach I gave you would work in the sense that you are not messing up the current object.  Replace all of your access to `matrix[ ][ ]` with `temp.matrix[ ][ ]`.  Also, you want to return a brand new object, not return a reference to the current object.  Either that, or the assignment given to you is wrong-headed, as what they should have had you overload would be `*=`, not `*`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've tried but i get this error  p_944972.cpp:62:21: error: type 'Matrica' does not provide a subscript operator
                temp[i][j]=tot;

Comment: @FilipGorgievski -- No. You would be doing `temp.matrix[][]`, just like you have `m.matrix[][]`.  The `matrix` is a member of the class, so that is what you are accessing.  Also, change the return value to `Matrica`, not `Matrica&`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thank you sir, that worked, I'am still learning proggraming and i make big mistakes.. Thanks again